# Can I link from my website to a certain section of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, wordpress, links

I write a blog on WordPress for my cosmetology school and I'm trying to link to a certain section of page in an external PDF from the MN Board of Cosmetology. I've been using `#page=` at the end of my links which works just fine, but it brings users to the top of the page and I'd like to see if I can direct them to a section specifically because rules and pages are changed frequently.

I also tried `#subsection.2105.0215` and that didn't work.

The PDF itself seems to have anchors as, if you click the subsection in the glossary, it brings you to the exact section. Is there a way I can access these anchors externally?

Any other ideas?

The PDF in question: https://www.revisor.mn.gov/rules/pdf/2105/2020-03-06%2012:37:19+00:00#page=27 and the subsection I'm trying to link to is 2105.0215 PROCEDURE FOR RENEWING AN EXPIRED LICENSE.

Answer (score 0):

Open the File and find the name of the bookmark you want to goto, and put that on the end of the url instead of page.

If your using Chrome, bookmarks are in the "Document Outline" section, and Adobe just has a bookmarks section. Other browsers etc will vary.

[image]

```
https://www.revisor.mn.gov/rules/pdf/2105/2020-03-06%2012:37:19+00:00#Part%202105.0215
```

The Bookmark for the section your looking for is "Part 202105.0215"

Links don't like spaces, so it becomes "Part%20202105.0215" (the %20 is just a url encoded space).